# Moq mocking Unit Test - implement code that will mock setup the GetAwaiter().GetResult() code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- .NET 6
- C# 10
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version  15.5.0
- Moq  Version 4.18.2
- Xunit  Version 2.4.1

```
public interface IBlahClient : IDisposable
{
   Task<IBlahResponse<TResponse>> SendQueryAsync<TResponse>(int 
           invocationNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public class BlahClient : IBlahClient
{

    public Task<IBlahResponse<TResponse>> SendQueryAsync<TResponse>( int invocationNumber,  
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return …;
    }
}
```

```
public class SUTClass
{   
    public bool BlahBlahMethod(IBlahClient blahClient)
    { 
        var resp = blahClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(5, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        // ...

        return …;
    }
}
```

```
public class SUTClassTests 
{
    [Fact]
    public void BlahTestMethod()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource< IBlahResponse <dynamic>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IBlahResponse<dynamic>>();
        
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(graphQLResponseMock.Object);
              
        Mock<IBlahClient> blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();
                        
        blahClientMock.Setup(c => c.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>( 5, CancellationToken.None))
                       .Returns(taskCompletionSource.Task);
              
        //Please show code that will Mock Setup the . GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Could someone please show me how to implement code that will mock setup the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` code?

Answer (score 2):

Moq does provide several ways to mock async methods

### Use `Setup` and `ReturnsAsync`

```
var blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();
blahClientMock
    .Setup(c => c.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(5, CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(graphQLResponseMock.Object);
```

### Use `Setup` with `.Result` and `Returns`

```
var blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();
blahClientMock
    .Setup(c => c.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(5, CancellationToken.None).Result)
    .Returns(graphQLResponseMock.Object);
```

[Here](https://github.com/moq/moq/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods) you can find more information

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain way to mock async methods ([from here](https://code-maze.com/csharp-mock-asynchronous-methods-using-moq/)):

```
blahClientMock.Setup(c => c.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>( 5, CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```